# When should I care about possible offset overflow?

Tags: c++, std

When I need to define an offset in array, should I care about possible overflow of the offset value in case it has the same `sizeof` the index in the array?

Formally, signed value offset has twice less range than unsigned value index and setting offset larger than half of the index addressed range overflows the offset variable, but technically I can’t see situation when such overflow could lead to issues due to

> C++ Standard 3.9.1.4 "Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic [modulo 2n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer."

and

> 5.3.1.8 "The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2n, where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand."

I assume this is safe to use the same size unsigned type for index and signed type for offset.

The required operations:

1. Add index and offset
2. Get element by the resulting new index
3. Compare two resulting indexes

No plans to compare two offsets which is a different story.

The [code](https://godbolt.org/z/1zqdd3PPs) below confirms this, but maybe I am missing something and this could lead to some issues?

```
#include <iostream>

using index_t = unsigned int;
using offset_t = signed int;

int main()
{
    index_t index = 100;
    const offset_t extra_offset = 1000;

    offset_t offset_large = std::numeric_limits<offset_t>::max() + extra_offset; // Forlmally overflows the offset

    long long int output_convestion;

    index_t position_large = index + offset_large;
    output_convestion = position_large;

    long long int position = index;
    position += std::numeric_limits<offset_t>::max();
    position += extra_offset;

    std::cout << "Position large = " << output_convestion << "  should be = " << position <<
        (output_convestion == position ? " (equal) " : "(different)") << '\n';
}
```

Why do I care and don’t just use larger size offset? I want to save memory on large arrays of offsets and, at the end of the day, what type would you use offset for `std::size_t` while `std::ptrdiff_t` in most known implementations use the same size, but signed, formally answering to this question from existing code perspective.

Comment: Is the goal here to enforce bounds checking, or to do the offset math correctly?

Comment: @tadman, at the moment I care about offset math only, not even including comparing two offsets. Just add index and offset, get another index, take element by index, and compare two indexes. Updated the question.

Comment: It generally helps to frame problems like this as functions which take input and give output, as that does allow testing more use cases efficiently.

Comment: @tadman, do you mean something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/8b4vso8vM)? If so, I will replace the code in the question, although I am not sure it is any better. If you had another idea in mind, could you please share?

Comment: In practice, you are highly unlikely to work with arrays having anywhere near `std::numeric_limits<offset_t>::max()` elements. You will have buffer overrun long before you have integer overflow. The underflow - computing a negative index and having it wrap around to a huge value - is a much more common bug.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<offset_t>::max() + extra_offset` Note that, while the standard specifies modulo arithmetic for unsigned integral types, it does *not* specify any particular behavior for signed integers. Your example contains an integer overflow, which is either undefined or implementation-defined behavior (I always forget which).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I wouldn't have asked if I am not. I work with gigabytes of data and `std::numeric_limits<signed int>::max()` is just 2Gb which often happens on my tasks. Having the chunk of 2Gb or 4Gb is a game changer in some situations. So, this makes sense for me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, can you pinpoint integer overflow here (or show by code example) which could lead to issues taking into account the standard quotes above?

Comment: `offset_t` is a signed integer type. `std::numeric_limits<offset_t>::max()` is the largest representable value of that type. You are adding a non-zero value to it; this exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows). Your quotes from the standard are about unsigned integers, which `offset_t` isn't.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you. Two questions here, then (1) What makes unsigned and signed so different that overflow of the former has well-documented behaviour and for the latter result in undefined behaviour? Both are just binary module2 representations, although with possible different representations of negative numbers on different platforms. (2) Why then the `std` suggests `std::ptrdiff_t` for `std::size_t` of the same sizes if such issues are possible as underwater stones? Or these should be a separate SO question?

Comment: `What makes unsigned and signed so different` At the time of standardization, compilers and computer architectures generally agreed on their handling of unsinged integer overflow, so it was codified into the standard. But they disagreed (and still do; [the article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows) I linked to gives examples) on the handling of signed integer overflow, so it was left unspecified. `Both are just binary module2 representations` on the architectures you are familiar with; other implementations exist.

Comment: `Why then the std suggests std::ptrdiff_t for std::size_t` Well, what else can it suggest? *Some* signed type is needed to represent a difference between two pointers. It's up to the program to avoid overflowing it, just as it's up to the program to avoid, say, dereferencing a null pointer, or myriad other instances of undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you. So, in this context, am I correct that widely recommended and used approach for `::npos = static_cast<size_t>(-1);` (like in std::basic_string) is incorrect and has undefined behaviour? Or negative signed constant is another story since doesn't involve "operation"?

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type; the standard explicitly specifies the result of casting a negative value to an unsigned integral type. `static_cast<size_t>(-1)` is well-defined in modulo `2^n` arithmetic.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I didn't mean `size_t` as `signed`, I meant `-1` as signed. So, am I correct that for signed **values** everything is fine, since they are not "signed operations"?

Comment: `-1` is an expression that applies a negation operator to a literal of type `int` with the value `1`. The result is a value `-1` of type `int`. This value falls within the range of values representable by type `int`; the expression in question is well defined. If that's what you are asking.